# Is @sendgrid/mail Node.js package affected by SendGrid's new requirement for TLS 1.2+?

Tags: node.js, heroku, sendgrid, tls1.2

SendGrid recently [announced](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/support-for-tls-12) that they're dropping support for TLS connections v1.1 and below. I'd like to know if this is relevant to my use case:

I use `@sendgrid/mail@^6.4.0` running within Docker on `node:16-alpine` on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

TSL support is enforced by the API endpoint, and therefore it shouldn't matter which client version you use. In either case, we recommend using the latest version (`7.7.0` at the time of this writing).

Comment: thank you but if we just use the api key for authentication then how do we ensure we're using the correct tls version? I don't determine a tls version anywhere, I assume it's implicitly determined somwhere.

Comment: Yes, it happens implicitly via your OS. There are more details on how to check whether your landscape supports this in the link that you mentioned above.